# Creating off-diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a data.frame as follows.

```
    > dat = matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ncol=4)
    > dat = as.data.frame(dat)
    > names(dat)[1]= "m1"
    > names(dat)[2]= "m2"
    > names(dat)[3]= "m3"
    > names(dat)[4]= "m4"
    > dat
      m1 m2 m3 m4
    1  0  1  0  2
    2  0  0  0  3
    3  1  1  0  4
    4  1  1  1  5
    5  1  1  1  6
```

I would like to create a matrix (4*4), which in the diagonal the values dat^2 and else for example 
dat[, 1] * dat[, 2], .... How can I do this in R? I know for the diagonal elements I can do

```
    > colSums(dat^2)
    m1 m2 m3 m4 
    3  4  2 90
```

Comment: Consider adding the full desired matrix to your post.

Comment: Is `crossprod(dat)` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AndreyShabalin pointed out, it sounds like you want `crossprod()`. Aslo, you will want to keep your data in a matrix format for this; no need for a data.frame.

```
dat = matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6), ncol=4)
colnames(dat)=c("m1","m2","m3","m4")
crossprod(dat)

#    m1 m2 m3 m4
# m1  3  3  2 15
# m2  3  4  2 17
# m3  2  2  2 11
# m4 15 17 11 90
```